# How to set different font configuration per monitor configuration? (on ElementaryOS 6 Odin)

Tags: fonts, hidpi, monitors

Abstract: LowDPI/HiDPI is saved per monitor configuration, but font size is shared for all configurations?

I have two different monitor configs:

- at home I have single HiDPI DELL 25" U-series
- at work I have two 1980x1080 24" DELLs

At home I use **2x Scale** which is set in Display Settings UI and then preserved in ~/.config/monitors.xml in separate **configuration** section.

[image: LowDPI/HiDPI is saved per monitor configuration]

At work configuration it is more comfortable to use **1x Scale** - it is saved in another **configuration** section of monitors.xml.

And there is another setting - "Font size" which I need to switch every time at start my home/work sessions. At home I setup "small font size" and at work - "larger".

[image: Font size is shared for all configurations]

Would you please tell me is there any opportunity to automatically switch the "Font size". Why it is not saved per **configuration** together with **scale** property?